# Assigning an If Statment formula to a variable AND select cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to assign an if/index/match formula to the a variable. The formula outputs the playerId that I need to use in a For Loop to find the value in a table and paste to the player information in the cells to the right.

Here is my code:

```
Public playerId as Range
Sub SubmitEdit()

Dim x As Long
Dim playRange As Range
Dim pcell As Range
Dim counter As Long

counter = 0
x = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Welcome").Range("A48").Value
Set playRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PlayerRecord").Range("A:A")

    lastRow = Sheets("PlayerRecord").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    'runtime error!!
    playerId.formula = "=IF($A46="""","""",INDEX(PlayerRecord!A:A,MATCH(INDEX(Registration!$A:$A,MATCH($A46,Registration!$C:$C,0)),PlayerRecord!$A:$A,0)))"
    For Each pcell In playRange.Cells
    counter = counter + 1
    If counter = lastRow Then Exit For
        If pcell.Value = playerId Then
            'Select row
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select

            'Go to PlayerRecord Worksheet and paste information
            Worksheets("Welcome").Range("B48:G48").Copy _
            Destination:=ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0)

            'ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        End If

        'Call HideSheets
        'returns to main sheet
        'Sheets("Welcome").Select
        'Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Next pcell
    Exit Sub
    End Sub
```

When I run the script a Runtime Error 91: Object variable or with block variable not set pops up.

Update: Changed the palyerID to Range and now getting the error: Runtime error 91 . Object Variable or with block not set

Comment: one question at a time, please. Summarize your first question, post only the relevant code.

Comment: You are declarding `playerId` as an Integer (a number) and then you are treating it as a `Range` and want to assign an entire formula to that number / cell / range here: `playerId.Formula = "=IF($A46="""","""",INDEX(Play...`. That cannot work.

Comment: @Ralph I changed playerId to a Range and am now getting another error. Run time error 424: Object Required for this code:

x = ThiWorkbook.Sheets("Welcome").Range("A46").Value

Comment: There is a typo. It should be `x = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Welcome").Range("A46").Value` and **not** `x = ThiWorkbook.Sheets("Welcome").Range("A46").Value`.

Comment: Let me guess, you are getting another error: `Object variable or With block variable not set` at the line with `playerid.Formula = "...`. That's because VBA doesn't know which cell you are trying to refer to with `playerid`. So, you'll have to `Set playerid = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SomeSheetInYourFile").Range("TheCellYouWantToReferTo")` first.

Comment: @Ralph Okay I see the issue..The reason I was assigning a variable was because I didnt want the playerId to be written to any cell. I just wanted to save the formula result as a value to use later in the code.

Comment: Then you should stick with `Integer` and use `playerId = Application.Evaluate("=IF($A46="""","""",INDEX(PlayerRecord!A:A,MATCH(INDEX(Registration!$A:$A,MATCH($A46,Registration!$C:$C,0)),PlayerRecord!$A:$A,0)))")`. Yet, this assumes that you get back a number between -32,768 and 32,767. If not, you'll get another error because `Integer` cannot store anything else.

Comment: @Ralph thank you that seems to have worked...I am now recieveing the same error  for the next line of code...any idea what is happening?

For Each pcell In playRange.Cells

Comment: Just change it to `For Each pcell In playRange`.

Comment: @Ralph thank you everything is working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having resolved all bugs the final working code should be:

```
Public playerId As Integer

Sub SubmitEdit()

Dim x As Long
Dim playRange As Range
Dim pcell As Range
Dim counter As Long

x = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Welcome").Range("A48").Value
Set playRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PlayerRecord").Range("A:A")
lastRow = Sheets("PlayerRecord").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
playerId = Application.Evaluate("=IF($A46="""","""",INDEX(PlayerRecord!A:A,MATCH(INDEX(Registration!$A:$A,MATCH($A46,Registration!$C:$C,0)),PlayerRecord!$A:$A,0)))")

counter = 0
For Each pcell In playRange
    counter = counter + 1
    If counter = lastRow Then Exit For
    If pcell.Value = playerId Then
        'Select row
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select

        'Go to PlayerRecord Worksheet and paste information
        Worksheets("Welcome").Range("B48:G48").Copy _
            Destination:=ActiveCell

        'ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End If

    'Call HideSheets
    'returns to main sheet
    'Sheets("Welcome").Select
    'Application.CutCopyMode = False
Next pcell

End Sub
```

A slightly improved version could be the following:

```
Sub SubmitEditVerions2()

Dim x As Long
Dim pcell As Range
Dim counter As Long
Dim playRange As Range
Dim playerId As Integer
Dim lastRow As Long

With ThisWorkbook
    If VarType(.Sheets("Welcome").Range("A48").Value) = vbLong Then
        x = .Sheets("Welcome").Range("A48").Value
    Else
        MsgBox "Error. Cell A48 on sheet 'Welcome' is not a number." & Chr(10) & "Aborting..."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Set playRange = .Sheets("PlayerRecord").Range("A:A")
    lastRow = .Sheets("PlayerRecord").Range("A" & .Sheets("PlayerRecord").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If VarType(Application.Evaluate("=IF($A46="""","""",INDEX(PlayerRecord!A:A,MATCH(INDEX(Registration!$A:$A,MATCH($A46,Registration!$C:$C,0)),PlayerRecord!$A:$A,0)))")) = vbInteger Then
        playerId = Application.Evaluate("=IF($A46="""","""",INDEX(PlayerRecord!A:A,MATCH(INDEX(Registration!$A:$A,MATCH($A46,Registration!$C:$C,0)),PlayerRecord!$A:$A,0)))")
    Else
        MsgBox "Error. Not a valid PlayerID." & Chr(10) & "Aborting..."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    counter = 0
    For Each pcell In playRange
        counter = counter + 1
        If counter = lastRow Then Exit For
        If pcell.Value = playerId Then
            'Select row
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select

            'Go to PlayerRecord Worksheet and paste information
            .Worksheets("Welcome").Range("B48:G48").Copy _
                Destination:=ActiveCell

            'ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        End If

        'Call HideSheets
        'returns to main sheet
        'Sheets("Welcome").Select
        'Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Next pcell
End With

End Sub
```